# Python - No module named 'fabric.api - Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, fabric

I just installed Python 3.7 and Fabric.

It works perfectly on my laptop, but not on my desktop.

The error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\python_project\myProject\env\Scripts\fab.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
File "c:\python_project\myProject\env\lib\site-packages\invoke\program.py", line 352, in run
self.parse_collection()
File "c:\python_project\myProject\env\lib\site-packages\invoke\program.py", line 444, in parse_collection
self.load_collection()
File "c:\python_project\myProject\env\lib\site-packages\fabric\main.py", line 82, in load_collection
super(Fab, self).load_collection()
File "c:\python_project\myProject\env\lib\site-packages\invoke\program.py", line 661, in load_collection
module, parent = loader.load(coll_name)
File "c:\python_project\myProject\env\lib\site-packages\invoke\loader.py", line 76, in load
module = imp.load_module(name, fd, path, desc)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\imp.py", line 235, in load_module
return load_source(name, filename, file)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\imp.py", line 172, in load_source
module = _load(spec)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 696, in _load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\python_project\myProject\fabfile.py", line 2, in <module>
from fabric.api import task, run, env, settings, hide
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fabric.api'
```

But Fabric seem to be installed ?

```
C:\Users\MyUser>pip install fabric
Requirement already satisfied: fabric in c:\program files (x86)\python37 32\lib\site-packages (2.4.0)

C:\Users\MyUser>pip show fabric
Name: fabric
Version: 2.4.0
Summary: High level SSH command execution
Home-page: http://fabfile.org
Author: Jeff Forcier
Author-email: jeff@bitprophet.org
License: BSD
Location: c:\program files (x86)\python37-32\lib\site-packages
Requires: paramiko, cryptography, invoke
Required-by:
```

However "fabric" didn't appear in the list when I do the following in idle (just Fabfile) :

```
>>> import pkgutil
>>> [name for _, name, _ in pkgutil.iter_modules()]
['fabfile', '_asyncio', '_bz2', ... 'enum', 'filecmp', 'fileinput', ...]
```

I also tried to uninstall/reinstall fabric, but it's still failing.

Do you have any idea why I cannot import fabric.api ?

Update :

I also created a virtual environment :

```
py -3 -m venv env 
code .
```

Selected Python interpreter "venv" in Visual Studio code then :

```
python -m pip install fabric
```

But i'm still facing the same error :-/

Answer (score 12):

Well after few research I finally found a workaround by using fabric3 (a fork of Fabric, compatible python 3).

```
pip uninstall fabric
pip install fabric3
```

Link : https://pypi.org/project/Fabric3/

Answer (score 3):

I see you have already installed `fabric 2.4.0` which is great! Since you are using the `fabric 2.4.0` you can't use `from fabric.api import taks`. `fabric.api` could be used if you use `fabric1xx`

If you want to import connection and task from `fabric2.4.0` you have to do it like this

```
from fabric import Connection as connection, task

@task
def deploy(ctx):
    with connection(host=host, user=user) as c:
         c.run('ls -la')
```

**Note:** fabric 3 is not an official fork. I advise you to use `fabric2.4.0`